# How to get custom message for ListView when there are no rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I need to show "There are no records" message when there are no rows for list view i want to show the message.

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Im aware this is an old question but I was looking for the same answer and came across this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8507/Indicating-an-empty-ListView-in-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending @Christian's answer:

Using code-bahind:

```
protected void ListView1_ControlRemoved (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var ListView1 = sender as ListView;
   if (ListVeew1.Items.Count == 0)
       ListView1.Items.Add("There are no records");
}
```

**OR** using markup:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        There are no records
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: If you use both, the ``<EmptyDataTemplate>`` will never be triggered, since the control will always contain one item..

Comment: @Christian: Right. I mean one or another. I edited the answer to be more clear.

Comment: This just adds another item to the listview which in turn becomes another item you have to validate before a null reference exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following markup:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="LstCustomer">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        Customer not found
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>You don't say what you are programming in...
But I believe the most common way to do this is to actually insert an item with the text "There are no records".</s>

You can use the `<EmptyDataTemplate>` to specify what to display when the data source is empty.